# modrewrite and redirect to https with www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite and redirect al ltrafic to https version. with www.
I have tried a lot of combinations and I can not find final solution.
Currently I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ppp.cz
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for if user enters url with www. Si I have tried to improve the code to (Where is condition for situation when url is without www.):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ppp.cz
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ppp\.cz
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it is still not doing what I need it to do.
I am currently hopeless.
(Condition with public/ is in all cases working.)
Could anyone help? Thank you

What I want to achieve is  *http://ppp.cz -> https://www.ppp.cz  ; http://www.ppp.cz -> https://www.ppp.cz*

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved it like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ppp\.cz
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.ppp.cz/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ppp.cz
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```